# Ruby on Rails - Windows 7 installation, non-english characters in user name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-7, installation

I'm trying to install Ruby on Rails on Windows 7 but I have a problem immediately at the beginning of the configuration. This is the first time I'm trying RoR.

I downloaded RailsInsaller from http://railsinstaller.org/ and installed it successfully. Immediately after the installation when I need to configure environment, I receive an error in cmd:

```
# Rails Environment Configuration.
open C:\\Users\\\246ero/.ssh/id_rsa failed: No such file or directory.
The system cannot find the path specified.
D:/ROR/RailsInstaller/scripts/config_check.rb:87:in `initialize': No such file o
r directory - C:\Users\|ero/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (Errno::ENOENT)
    from D:/ROR/RailsInstaller/scripts/config_check.rb:87:in `open'
    from D:/ROR/RailsInstaller/scripts/config_check.rb:87:in `<main>'
```

What is the solution to this problem? Or is there any other way to install RoR on Windows 7? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old post, but I had the same issue, and I think I've found the solution.
The path that ssh is trying to access contains that character "|" that Ruby doesn't like, that's because your username is "|ero".

To resolve this issue, you should either change your windows username (this should prevent you from a lot of troubles in your future setup), or change your HOME environment variable so that it points to a folder that doesn't contain any accent, space or strange character in its path ! And then re-install Ruby :)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Ruby on Rails in Windows 7. To install ruby on rails on Windows7 follow the steps:

1) install ruby on windows 7. Download from: http://rubyinstaller.org/

2) check ruby is installed correctly by this command `ruby -v` if this gives command not found error, then set RUBY_HOME="path/to/ruby/bin" in environment variables.

3) install rails by command `gem install rails`.

and you are done. Enjoy Ruby On Rails on Windows7.

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly the same problem and found its solution - under Windows XP Pro SP3. You should manually generate the ssh keys pair. Run ssh-keygen from a bash
shell so it generated both id_rsa and id_rsa.pub.

That's easy as 3 mouseclicks:

Start - Programs - Rails Installer - Git Bash

type there "ssh-keygen". Press Enter 2 or 3 times. You're done! The problem is gone now.